# Remove elements from a flat array using a flat blacklist array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-difference, blacklist

So I have two arrays:

```
$one = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'white');
$two = array('white', 'blue', 'red');
```

This being said, I need to now remove the elements from the first array that are existent in the second one. In short, the output after the sorting has to be (in this case): `['green', 'yellow']`.

I've looked at the array functions at PHP's documentation but was unable to find what I need. I'm sure it's something basic but I can't recall a function for that.

Comment: array_diff is the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-diff.php)

> Compares **`array1`** against one or more other arrays and returns the values in **`array1`** that are not present in any of the other arrays.

For example...

```
$three = array_diff($one, $two);
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/167872